# Interval of Concavity and Inflection point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, eulers-number-e

I was wondering if there is any way of finding an interval of concavity for a function if the second derivative is undefined for $x$. The function we got was $f(x)=e^x + e^{-3x}$. I realised halfway through trying to find $f''(x)$ that it is undefined.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why do you say the derivative is undefined?

Comment: The second derivative of this function is perfectly well defined. I think you should post your calculation so someone can explain where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$f''(x)=e^x+9e^{-3x}$. The equation $f''(x)=0$ has no real solutions for $x$, thus $f$ never changes concavity. $f''(0)=1+9=10 > 0$ thus $f$ is concave up across all of $\mathbb{R}$.